# readdir() does not give me '.' and '..' directories on Arch Linux Manjaro but it does on NixOS

Tags: c, readdir

On NixOS `readdir` give me at first the `..` and `.` directories.
But on Manjaro Arch Linux the `readdir` function does not give those directories.

Example :

```
DIR *dir = opendir('.');
struct dirent *dir_info;
while ((dir_info = readdir(dir)))
{
    printf("%s/n");
}
```

On NixOS it gives me :

```
..
.
foo/
toto/
```

But on Arch Linux I have :

```
foo/ toto/
```

Does anyone have a clue to fix that ? In order to get `.` `..` directories.

Comment: You don't need `..` and `.`. But if you really do, wrap `readdir` into a function of your's and add them yourself if they don't show up.

Comment: BTW: `printf("%s/n");` is UB, please show real code.

Comment: I guess the `opendir('.')` above is a typo? The parameter should be a string. To echo the above comment, please show real code.

Comment: Posix says "If entries for dot or dot-dot exist, one entry shall be returned for dot and one entry shall be returned for dot-dot; otherwise, they shall not be returned." So I guess maybe they don't exist on your system for that specific directory for some reason. Do you get them when you run `ls -a` in that directory?

Comment: `readdir` is only a function from the Posix library. It relies on a file system implementation for the actual content of a directory. If *in the underlying filesystem* directories have entries for `.` and `..` then `readdir` will return them. If they are not present, it will not.